# Overriding history.pushState leads to error in opera 11

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, history, opera

I'm injecting the following code into a webpage via a greasemonkey script/opera extension to trap the `history.pushState` command, so I can do some processing whenever it's fired and still allow the `pushState` command to continue afterwards.

```
(function(history){
  var pushState = history.pushState;
  history.pushState = function(state) {
       if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
          history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        alert('pushstate called')
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
  }
})(window.history);
```

the code works fine in FF4 and Chrome, but in Opera 11, I get the following error, if the page calls a `history.replaceState` command:

> Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'window.history.replaceState' is not a function

Does anyone know how I can fix the above code to work with Opera as well as Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

In Opera 11.00, Revision 1156, the history API supported are these

```
>>> history.
back, current, forward, go, length, navigationMode
```

The full [HTML5 history API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#the-history-interface) is not yet covered by Opera 11.00. In general if you would like to discover, explore what is supported, you can easily use the console mode of [dragonfly](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/), the Web developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

According to [When can I use …](http://caniuse.com/history) Opera doesn't support the History API yet, so that's why you get that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, just check for `history.replacestate` before executing the above code, if it doesn't exist, don't execute the code, simple.

Comment: i am the author, why would i need to critique or request clarification from myself?

Comment: `Does anyone know how I can fix the above code to work with Opera as well as Chrome and Firefox?`. This doesn't provide an answer to the question, but rater excludes the method if it not supported.